# AzerothCore module configuration not found

Tags: azerothcore

I got problem with my modules, since the .dist/.conf seems to not be found (they're on the same folder as the two server .exe)

So I listed what I use and put in () if there is a problem (the core is fresh core from 01/19/2019 at 7 pm), also I change the .dist to .conf and it didn't fix the issues:

-Account achievement

-BG Reward (seems to get some bug, but I'm in local I can't test it for now)

-chat login (seems to don't work)

-congrats on level

-mod eluna engine

-fireworks on level (I don't see fireworks)

-mod individual XP

-mod instance reset

-item level up

-notify when muted

-npc gambler (since the git pull the 19/01 at 7 pm I can't spam the answers, but I have to quit the dialog box and retalk to him, but no other bug except that)

-phased duel

-mod premium (can't open the book anymore, since the last git pull too)

-mod start guild (seems to don't put people on a guild)

-mod transmog (I can transmog, but the setting are unfound)

`I also put my server.log in pastebin :`

https://pastebin.com/FZwKEuSW

And at connection I got :

-This server is running the StartGuild module.

-This server is running PhasedDuels  module.

-This server is running GamblerNPC module.

-This server is running IndividualXpRate module.

-This server is running CustomServer (must be fireworks) module.

-This server is running CongratsOnLevel module.

-This server is running AccountAchievements module.

EDIT :

To show you what error I got in my worldserver.exe :

> Not found option 'Gambler.Amount1'. The default value is used (1)
>
> Not found option 'Gambler.Amount2'. The default value is used (2)
>
> Not found option 'Gambler.Amount3'. The default value is used (3)
>
> Not found option 'Gambler.Amount4'. The default value is used (4)
>
> Not found option 'Gambler.Amount5'. The default value is used (5)
>
> Not found option 'Gambler.Jackpot'. The default value is used (50)
>
> Not found option 'Transmogrification.EnableSetInfo'. The default value is used (Yes)
>
> Not found option 'Transmogrification.SetNpcText'. The default value is used (50001)
>
> Not found option 'Transmogrification.EnableSets'. The default value is used (Yes)
>
> Not found option 'Transmogrification.MaxSets'. The default value is used (10)
>
> Not found option 'Transmogrification.SetCostModifier'. The default value is used (3.000000)
>
> Not found option 'Transmogrification.SetCopperCost'. The default value is used (0)
>
> Not found option 'Transmogrification.EnableTransmogInfo'. The default value is used (Yes)
>
> Not found option 'Transmogrification.TransmogNpcText'. The default value is used (50000)
>
> Not found option 'Transmogrification.Allowed'. The default value is used ()
>
> Not found option 'Transmogrification.NotAllowed'. The default value is used ()
>
> Not found option 'Transmogrification.ScaledCostModifier'. The default value is used (1.000000)
>
> Not found option 'Transmogrification.CopperCost'. The default value is used (0)
>
> Not found option 'Transmogrification.RequireToken'. The default value is used (No)
>
> Not found option 'Transmogrification.TokenEntry'. The default value is used (49426)
>
> Not found option 'Transmogrification.TokenAmount'. The default value is used (1)
>
> Not found option 'Transmogrification.AllowPoor'. The default value is used (No)
>
> Not found option 'Transmogrification.AllowCommon'. The default value is used (No)
>
> Not found option 'Transmogrification.AllowUncommon'. The default value is used (Yes)
>
> Not found option 'Transmogrification.AllowRare'. The default value is used (Yes)
>
> Not found option 'Transmogrification.AllowEpic'. The default value is used (Yes)
>
> Not found option 'Transmogrification.AllowLegendary'. The default value is used (No)
>
> Not found option 'Transmogrification.AllowArtifact'. The default value is used (No)
>
> Not found option 'Transmogrification.AllowHeirloom'. The default value is used (Yes)
>
> Not found option 'Transmogrification.AllowMixedArmorTypes'. The default value is used (No)
>
> Not found option 'Transmogrification.AllowMixedWeaponTypes'. The default value is used (No)
>
> Not found option 'Transmogrification.AllowFishingPoles'. The default value is used (No)
>
> Not found option 'Transmogrification.IgnoreReqRace'. The default value is used (No)
>
> Not found option 'Transmogrification.IgnoreReqClass'. The default value is used (No)
>
> Not found option 'Transmogrification.IgnoreReqSkill'. The default value is used (No)
>
> Not found option 'Transmogrification.IgnoreReqSpell'. The default value is used (No)
>
> Not found option 'Transmogrification.IgnoreReqLevel'. The default value is used (No)
>
> Not found option 'Transmogrification.IgnoreReqEvent'. The default value is used (No)
>
> Not found option 'Transmogrification.IgnoreReqStats'. The default value is used (No)
>
> Not found option 'StartGuild.Enable'. The default value is used (Yes)
>
> Not found option 'StartGuild.Announce'. The default value is used (Yes)
>
> Not found option 'GamblerNPC.Announce'. The default value is used (Yes)
>
> Not found option 'CustomServer.Announce'. The default value is used (Yes)
>
> Not found option 'LoginChat.name'. The default value is used (world)
>
> Not found option 'PhasedDueling.Enable'. The default value is used (Yes)

It seems the modules always take the default value, but their .conf/.conf.dist aren't found

Answer (score 4):

The reason why this is happening is because AC is recognizing your /conf files in question as Dist Files.. its a very known bug on Windows.

Simply open each config file that's not being detected, open each file, select-all copy, then open a new file with Notepad paste what you copied in the new file and save it as xxxx.conf / make sure your "Save As Type" Window shows "All files" / ANSI "

The reason why is because Windows is still seeing them as DIST files and CONF

Answer (score 1):

Thank you everyone, I tried on Ubuntu 18.04 and it seems to work, so for Windows it seems to be a bug like Illuminatus said.

And thank you Barbz_YHOOL for the explaination